# How to insert into my table from a file in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a `file.dat` that is as follow:

```
"Evan","E","Wallis","222222200","1958-01-16","134 Pelham, Milwaukee, WI","M","92000.00",null,"7"
"Jared","D","James","111111100","1966-10-10","123 Peachtree, Atlanta, GA","M","85000.00",null,"6"
```

I would like to insert these values into my table.

I tried the following but I did not succeed.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/file.dat" 
INTO TABLE table
;
```

There is no error but there is a warning and the table is not filled with the data.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/file.dat" INTO TABLE table
0 row(s) affected, 64 warning(s):
1265 Data truncated for column 'fname' at row 1
1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns...
```

Here is how the `table` is created.

```
CREATE TABLE table(
  fname    varchar(15) not null, 
  minit    varchar(1),
  lname    varchar(15) not null,
  ssn      char(9),
  bdate    date,
  address  varchar(50),
  sex      char,
  salary   decimal(10,2),
  superssn char(9),
  dno      integer(4),
  primary key (ssn),
  foreign key (superssn) references employee(ssn)
);
```

Comment: How exactly did it *not work*? Any error messages you can add to this question?

Comment: Okay, I edited the question. Sadly, I cannot add a snapshot figure since my reputation is too small. However the warning message is too long.

Comment: @5.r.a Maybe, number of columns in file doesn't match number of columns in the table? Look here: "Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns"

Comment: I do not think so. Look I edited my question to include the `CREATE TABLE table` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MySQL is looking for a tab-separated file.  Try the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:/file.dat" 
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have a field which is not enclosed by "" which is the `null` value. Can I specify that too?

Comment: Yes:  change my original  example, above to say:   `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`